# How do I set the Text in tkinter size to the size of the main window?

Tags: python, tkinter, text, resize

I had created a text area in tkinter and I want its size to fit the Tk() each time I resize the window!
This is my Code:

```py
from tkinter import *

#The window:
app = Tk()

#The size of the screen:
s_width = app.winfo_screenwidth()
s_height = app.winfo_screenheight()

#The text area:
text_area = Text(app, width = s_width, height = s_height)
text_area.place(x = 0, y = 0)

#mainloop
app.mainloop()
```

But this gives a weird size to the text_area!
I want the *text_area* to be at the size of the *app* variable!
How can I do it?
It should resize every time I resize the screen!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You created a very big `Text` box as you used the screen resolution as the width and height of the text box.  Note that `width` and `height` options of `Text` widget are in characters, not pixels.  So for a screen resolution of `1920x1080`, then you created a `Text` box with 1920 characters width and 1080 lines height.

To make the text box resize along with the root window, you can use `relwidth` and `relheight` options of `place()`:

```py
from tkinter import *

#The window:
app = Tk()

#The text area:
text_area = Text(app)
text_area.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)

#mainloop
app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

`text_area.place(x = 0, y = 0)`

- I Guess Try to Put Your value
  Try to refer docs *
- docs can be founded [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html#:%7E:text=The%20tkinter%20package%20(%E2%80%9CTk%20interface,it%20is%20maintained%20at%20ActiveState.))

Comment: I think, hmm... That is not the correct answer! Or may be?